# Issues while upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: upgrade, 17.04, 17.10

I was trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 through the update manager. The packages were all downloaded and they were getting installed.

Meanwhile the screen got locked and from there I wasn't able to proceed further. The password field won't accept any characters showing "Authentication Failed". The power button options didn't seem to work. The UI seemed all broken. I had no option but to restart and since then I'm stuck at the Ubuntu home screen which shows 5 dots at the bottom (at the time of start-up).

**Question:**

I know I can recover my important files by making a bootable flashdrive. Is there a way I can rollback to Ubuntu 17.04? Anything to try out before I wipe it all out?

Comment: No way to roll back, boot a 17.10 live usb, if everything works, copy / back up your files and install.

Comment: There seemed some issue with 17.10 itself. Couldn't install it through bootable USB as well. Installed 16.04 and now I'm at peace.